# unable to open jupyter notebook using command prompt, tried installing again and again differently

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I ran `jupyter notebook` and I'm getting the following error. Please help!

I checked the conda version, it's working fine. I added paths in the environment variables. I don't know why it isn't working. Previously it worked fine I recently uninstalled it and installed it again.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
        from notebook.notebookapp import main
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 51, in <module>
        from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
        from zmq import backend
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
        reraise(*exc_info)
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
        raise value
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
        _ns = select_backend(first)
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
        mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        from . import (constants, error, message, context,
    ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.

getting this error, 
please help!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be an issue with the 64bit version of Anaconda, Try these steps:

1. Install Anaconda 32 Bit for windows.
2. Add \Anaconda3 and \Anaconda3\Script to Path in Environment variables.
3. Open Anaconda Prompt and Create an Environment and activate it.
4. Once you activate the Environment, you will into it. Then write the command JUPYTER
   NOTEBOOK, it should run on your Browser.

If that dose not work you can go back and install a bit older version of Anaconda and try doing the same.

Here for more help (: